# How can I align two Pivots on the same page?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to align two pivots on the same page, four PivotItem on the left and one on the right, but I have no idea on how to get this working.

Comment: You can use Hamburger Menus

Answer (score 0):

If you want align two Pivots on the same page, you can use the [`ColumnDefinitions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Grid_ColumnDefinitions) to set Column of the Grid. Then we can put one `Pivot` in the left Column, another `Pivot` in the right Column.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Pivot Grid.Column="0">
        <PivotItem Header="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1"></TextBlock>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="1">
            <TextBlock Text="2"></TextBlock>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="3">
            <TextBlock Text="3"></TextBlock>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="4">
            <TextBlock Text="4"></TextBlock>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
    <Pivot Grid.Column="1">
        <PivotItem Header="1">
            <TextBlock Text="1"></TextBlock>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```